# Trying to find URL's in a file and save to a dictionary?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

For my coding assignment I am to find all URL's in a mem.raw file and then save the URL's and how many of each was found in a prettytable and output it.  The code that seems to be the issue if the "for URL in fileContents" but I can't figure out why.  It's iterating over this for loop but isn't finding the matches and saving it to the dictionary.  Any ideas why?

Here is the code I have

```
import re
import os
import sys
from prettytable import PrettyTable

largeFile = input("Enter the name of a large File: ")
chunkSize = int(input("What size chunks?  "))

urlPattern      = re.compile(b'\w+:\/\/[\w@][\w.:@]+\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*')
matches = {}

try:
    if os.path.isfile(largeFile):
        with open(largeFile, 'rb') as targetFile:
            fileContents = targetFile.read(chunkSize)


            


            print("\nURLs")

            for URL in fileContents:
                try:
                    urlMatches   = urlPattern.findall(fileContents)
                    cnt = matches[URL]
                    cnt += 1
                    matches[URL] = cnt
                except:
                    matches[URL] = 1


            tbl = PrettyTable(["Words", "Occurrences"])
            for word, cnt in matches.items():
                tbl.add_row([word, cnt])
                tbl.align = '1'
                print(tbl.get_string(sortby="Occurrences", reversesort=True))
                break
    else:
        print(largeFile, " is not a valid file")
        sys.exit("Script Aborted")

except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code does not make sense. Not even sure why the while loop is there.

```
for eachURL in urlMatches:
    while True:
        matches = matches[eachURL]
```

You'll need to do something like

```
for URL in urlMatches:
    if URL not in matches:
        matches[URL] = 1
    else:
        matches[URL] += 1
```

Now that you have edited the question, new issues arise.
The following should work:

```
fileContents = targetFile.read(chunkSize)
urlMatches   = urlPattern.findall(fileContents)

for URL in urlMatches:
    if URL not in matches:
        matches[URL] = 1
    else:
        matches[URL] += 1
```

Note that you'll need an outer loop to cover the file contents after chunk size.

Comment: I changed that, the issue is when I print matches it still only ever prints the first results.  Also I need to print all the results and containing how many of each there is.  Like if google.com was hit 5 times it shows google.com 5

Comment: I have hosted an online example here: https://onecompiler.com/python/3yg944cyv

Comment: I just updated the question.  I don't think I was being very clear before, so hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The above code I have is working.  The issue is I think it's saving the matches by their indentation number or something?  For example some are saving as 245:1.  It's a raw data file so I'm not even sure what the contents are, it's for a class assignment.

Comment: Updated the answer again. URL are in urlMatches, not filecontents.

Comment: The thing I can't figure out is why it isn't finding matches properly and storing them.  It's finding numbers and storing them for some reason.